# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation during FileSystem.get()

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, hdfs

Please find attached a code snippet. I am using this code to download files from hdfs to my local file system -

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    FileSystem hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

    Path local = new Path(destinationPath);
    Path hdfs = new Path(sourcePath);

    String fileName = hdfs.getName();

    if (hdfsFileSystem.exists(hdfs))
    {
        hdfsFileSystem.copyToLocalFile(false, hdfs, local, true);
        logger.info("File " + fileName + " copied to local machine on location: " + destinationPath);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.error("File " + fileName + " does not exist on HDFS on location: " + sourcePath);
    }
```

Running this gives the following output -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2624)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2634)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
at com.flipkart.ads.importer.HdfsToLocalImporter.importFile(HdfsToLocalImporter.java:35)
at com.flipkart.ads.importer.HdfsToLocalImporter.main(HdfsToLocalImporter.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Resolved**

Didn't cross my mind. It was a jar mismatch issue. Hadoop-code and Hadoop-commons provide the same jars and I had included both the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Check your build path.If you see hadoop-core*****.jar there, remove that. It is not needed. That will resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You just need to point your Configuration object towards your hdfs server.  Use
 `conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://urlhere:8020");`

Comment: tried `conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");`. Doesn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `conf.addResources`. You initialized `Configuration` object but it is still empty.

Check [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) for documentation

**EDIT:**
Try this:

`conf.addResource(new Path("<absolute file path>"))`

Comment: what resources do I need to add? I did something like this
`conf.addResource("/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/etc/hadoop/core-default.xml");`
core-site, hdfs-site??

Comment: @frugalcoder its been a while since I worked with hdfs but I guess it is most likely configuration `xml` file

Comment: @frugalcoder maybe this: `conf.addResource(new File("../resource.xml").toURI().toURL());`

Comment: I get file not found exception. even though the file is there.