# UnsupportedOperationException while running oozie job

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run oozie map reduce job available in examples of oozie. After running command:

```
bin/oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run i got unsupportedexception.
```

oozie version: 4.3.0
hadoop version: 2.7.1
on web console 500 internal server error.

stacktrace:

```
2017-08-15 01:32:10,772 ERROR V1JobsServlet:517 - SERVER[heena-lenovo-b560] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] URL[POST http://localhost:11000/oozie/v2/jobs?action=start] error, Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2634)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$4.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:565)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$4.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:563)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createFileSystem(HadoopAccessorService.java:563)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.AuthorizationService.authorizeForApp(AuthorizationService.java:374)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobServlet.checkAuthorizationForApp(BaseJobServlet.java:260)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobsServlet.doPost(BaseJobsServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:304)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:554)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:610)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is value of property fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml on machine where you are running oozie job? And what is corresponding error in hdfs logs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation during FileSystem.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015753/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-not-implemented-by-the-distributedfiles)

Comment: Did you build Oozie with hadoop version 2.7.1 and the actual Hadoop cluster is also 2.7.1? Is it a version conflict?
What did you set for ``oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.supported.filesystems`` in ``oozie-site.xml``? As questioned above, what is ``fs.defaultFS`` of Oozie's ``core-site.xml`` set to?

Comment: it was version conflict. I set oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.supported.filesystems  to * but after upgrading oozie version, it worked fine