# Is it possible to read a file using SparkSession object of Scala language on Windows?

Tags: windows, scala, file, apache-spark

I've been trying to read from a .csv file on many ways, utilizing `SparkContext` object. I found it possible through `scala.io.Source.fromFile` function, but I want to use spark object. Everytime I run function `textfile` for `org.apache.spark.SparkContext` I get the same error:

```
scala>     sparkSession.read.csv("file://C:\\Users\\184229\\Desktop\\bigdata.csv")


21/12/29 16:47:32 WARN streaming.FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
.....
```

As it's mentioned in the title I run the code on Windows in IntelliJ

[Edit]
In build.sbt have no redundant or overlapped dependencies. I use hadoop-tools, spark-sql and hadoop-xz.

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015753/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-not-implemented-by-the-distributedfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, precisely one of my colleague did that.
In dependencies build.sbt I changed hadoop-tools to hadoop-commons and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your spark-shell using local mode?

```scala
spark-shell --master=local
```

Also pay attention to not use both Hadoop-code and Hadoop-commons as a dependencies since you may have conflicting jars issues.

Comment: I enabled locale mode by adding 
`val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark2-compress").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()`